# Проблема отображения joomla сайта на мобильном

Tags: css, joomla

Есть сайт на Joomla 2.5. Сделан на основе шаблона Zoo_Template_Hosting. В шаблоне встроен слайдер главной страницы. mod_zt_headline. Проблема заключается в следующем: при открытии сайта на мобильном телефоне (конкретно iphone/safari, на android/chrome этой проблемы нет) все открывается нормально. Как только слайдер листает следующий материал, он начинает отображаться некорректно, а именно сбивается размер шрифта (шрифт увеличивается) и текст уползает за область слайдера. Необходимо настроить корректное отображение сайта. Повторюсь, проблема только в сафари на яблоках.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]